# Using static vars in PHP functions

Tags: php

The use of the static $var in this function works, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to handle a situation like this.

```
function static_test() {
    static $var = FALSE;
    if ( ! $var) $var = date('Ymd');
    // do some stuff with $var
}
```

I wondered if possible to do something closer to this... or other to declare the static $var.

```
function static_test() {
    static $var = date('Ymd');
    // do some stuff with $var
}
```

How would you do it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I think this is a good read for you http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php, specificaly where it talks about static variables search for "Using static variables" on the page, you can't declare a static variable with an expression it even has some nice examples

Comment: I can't think of a better, or more clear way to explain it than in the second example above.  I wondered if there might be a way to declare a static var with the value of a function.  I know it can be done something like the first example.

Comment: No, static variables can only be assigned values that are not the result of expressions

Comment: @rroche, thanks.  So you'd also do it like the first example then?

Comment: @Poe Based on the manual I think you dont need to check for its initial value, you can just override, once you do it will remain that new value until you change it again, check Example #6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is almost fine. As you may read here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php,

> ...[a static variable] is initialized only in first call of function...

So there is no need for this piece of code: `if ( ! $var) $var = date('Ymd');`

However, you need a dummy:

`$dummy=date('Ymd'); 
static $var=$dummy;`

Comment: thanks @Alfredo for taking the time to answer the question with an option that works, instead of downvoting and leaving a non-constructive comment.

Comment: Did you test the $dummy initialization of $var ? I have my doubts as it specifically states not liking expressions on the values,

Comment: @rroche, I didn't test it.  Since this question was being downvoted I didn't bother further.  I resolved that my 1st example that worked would be the way I continue to code it if I need a static var in a function.

Answer (score 0):

The second example is simply not in php syntax. I loathe static var usage at all, but especially in this instance. I would use a class.